# Solution for SSL client certificates with user self service

Tags: vpn, authentication, ssl-certificate, certificate, certificate-authority

I'm administrating a linux-based small business network. User information is centrally stored in an OpenLDAP directory. There is an existing CA which is currently used to sign server certificates. It is managed using EasyRSA. My current project is to setup a VPN for remote access to the network as well as an 802.1X based WiFi. I'd like to use client certificates for both.

I'd like to avoid having to create each client certificate manually. Ideally, there would be a web service that authenticates users against LDAP and allows them to create a signed client certificate without administrator intervention. An intermediate CA for such a service could be made.

Is there a project, free or commercial, that allows me to do this? Ideally Linux based since that would fit the existing environment best. During research I stumbled upon OpenCA and EJBCA and those seem highly configurable. But it remains unclear whether or not those are capable of providing this functionality.

Addition:
[I've found a guide](http://networklessons.com/wireless/eap-tls-certificates-for-wireless-on-android/) mentioning Active Directory Certificate Services which seems to be basically what I need. Scroll down to "Generate User Certificate on Windows 7" which shows the process. However, since this is not a windows network, another solution without Active Directory is preferred.

Comment: I've created certs for years by hand with OpenSSL. It really doesn't take more than 10 minutes even when I have to review my notes and copy out the obscure command line syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a Makefile to deal with this. So I never need to remember any openssl command! :-)
I used it to enroll server certs and client certs and even certificates on smartcards.
I can also revoke certificates and publish the CRL.

Hm, I just created a repo on [github](https://github.com/cornelinux/simple-ca-makefile), so that you can take a look at.

OpenCA is rather cool and mighty. But I think it is not activley maintained anymore.
The user would enroll his certificate in the browser, but afterwards he would have to export the certificate...

Comment: The LDAP part is definitely interesting. I will look at this, thanks alot for sharing! It seems as if there is no fully automated solution. So having a half-automated makefile seems like a good compromise. Maybe I'll add this into easy-rsa.

Comment: ...or fork it on github and do a pull request ;-)